# How to define set-struct like java's bean with handreds of distinct element

Tags: haskell

I'd like to define a fixed set of values, they are all integral, 
but elements are with different type(Int8/Int16/Int32/Integer).

the type of each element is fixed, and there will be only get/set
functions. like 'java beans'.

with my intuition, It may be:

> data MyFixedSet = MyFixedSet {getva :: Int32, getvb :: Int8, 
>                           getvc :: Integer, ... , getvxx :: Int16}

or use tuples:

> data MyFixedSet = MyFixedSet (Int32,Int8,Integer, ... Int16)

or :

> type MyFixedSet = (Int32,Int8,Integer, ... Int16)

then I what to have functions to operate with it:

> getVA (va,*,*,.....,*) = va
>   setVA (*,vb,vc,.....vxx) va = (va,vb,vc,...vxx)
>   getVA (*,vb,*,.....,*) = vb
>   setVA (va,*,vc,.....vxx) vb = (va,vb,vc,...vxx)
>   ...

but I think they are too heavy to use, in my case, there will be 
200~500 elements in a set.

Should I use Map?
if I do this:

> data Elem = X8 Int8 | X16 Int16 | ... | XI Integer
>   let set = Map.fromList [(0, X32 1234), (1, X8 666), ...]
>   then I have to do some Type-check when I extract things from Map.

I'd like to know is there is a 'beautiful' and 'efficient' way to do this?

**how about their performance?**

Comment: You know you can update a record field with `r { field = x }`?  That said, records with hundreds of fields would be inefficient to update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The record-based solution may indeed be too heavy, especially when updating values. Considering the values in Haskell are immutable, every record update requires construction of a new object. In your case this object will be quite large, so its construction may be slow. `Maps` should be faster.

Now, to make `Map`s more type-safe, How about storing one map per your data type?

```
data MyFixedSet = MyFixedSet (IntMap Int8) (IntMap Int16) (IntMap Int32) (IntMap Integer)
```

This way you don't have to type-check extracted values, but you have to lookup the right map.

Returning to the record-based solution, one can improve performance by splitting the large data structure in several parts, like a tree:

```
data MyFixedSet = MyFixedSet Part1 Part2 Part3 Part4
data Part1 = Part1 Part1SubPart1 Part1SubPart2 Part1SubPart3
....
data Part1SubPart1 = Part1SubPart1 Int32 Int8 Integer
....
```

You can even do this automatically and generate some nice accessor functions with the help of *Template Haskell*.

Comment: Thank you! I will use your first suggestion, I's great!

Comment: data MyFixedSet = MyFixedSet (IntMap Int8) (IntMap Int16) (IntMap Int32) (IntMap Integer)
:)

Comment: Then don't forget to look at camccann's improvement. It's actually great!

Answer (score 2):

In the first lump of code

```
data MyFixedSet = MyFixedSet {
    getva :: Int32, 
    getvb :: Int8
    -- and so on
} deriving (Show)
```

Haskell will automatically generate functions for you with the type signatures

```
getva :: MyFixedSet -> Int
getvb :: MyFixedSet -> Int
```

But it also allows you to do record based updates as well.

```
*Main> let x = MyFixedSet 3 4
*Main> x { getva = 7 }
MyFixedSet {getva = 7, getvb = 4}
```

And you can even update as many fields as you like with the same syntax e.g.

```
x { getva = 1234, getvb = 101 }
```

Based on this I think the first way you described, known as [record syntax](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/defining-types-streamlining-functions.html#deftypes.record), is the way to go.  You get type safe accessor and update functions generated automatically for you.

Comment: I think the concern in this particular case is that, for a truly monstrous record size, the allocation overhead of recreating the record for each update may be significant, even if field values are shared. But I'm not sure how GHC might handle this internally.

Comment: Yes, I think I misunderstood the question, though since there was no mention of the record update syntax, it's probably useful to keep around.

Comment: You'd think GHC could share the unchanged portions, or even overwrite the old one if it detects that it will not be used any more.

Comment: @Dan: I suspect that would become awkward in the presence of GC, thunks, and non-strictness. In particular, my understanding is that product types are essentially atomic, the entire structure being forced in one go. Reusing parts of structures could result in weird situations where strictness is inconsistent or memory is wasted by references to partial structures or who knows what else. So it makes sense, but it'd be difficult to get it right. See also the ways that `(x,y,z)` is different from `(x,(y,z))`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a slight variation on the `Data.Map` approach:

```
module HugeRecord where

import qualified Data.Map as Map
import Data.Map (Map, (!))

type IntFields = Map IntField Int 
type StringFields = Map StringField String

data HugeRecord = HugeRecord { intFields    :: IntFields
                             , stringFields :: StringFields
                             } deriving (Eq, Show)

data IntField = IntField1 | IntField2 | IntField3
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Enum, Bounded)

data StringField = StringField1 | StringField2 | StringField3
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Enum, Bounded)


initFields :: (Bounded k, Enum k, Ord k) => v -> Map k v
initFields z = Map.fromList $ zip [minBound .. maxBound] (repeat z)


newRecord = HugeRecord (initFields 0) (initFields "")


setIntField rcd fld x = rcd { intFields = Map.insert fld x (intFields rcd) }
setStringField rcd fld x = rcd { stringFields = Map.insert fld x (stringFields rcd) }

getIntField rcd fld = intFields rcd ! fld
getStringField rcd fld = stringFields rcd ! fld
```

For each type of field, define an enumerated data type, then construct a `Map` using default values and only provide get/set functions to ensure that the map always contains a key for every field.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want to have a set of values, but their types are not known before hand, altough they are from a fixed set of types.

In that case I might do something like this:

```
data MyFixedSet = SetA Int32 | SetB Int16 | ....

instance Eq MyFixedSet where
    (SetA x) == y = fromIntegral x == y
    (SetB x) ...
```

And similarly the `Ord` instance.

Then you can have it set in a Set if you wish.

```
type Foo = Set MyFixedSet
```